# How to convert existing code into WooCommerce Plugin

Tags: wordpress

Im extremely new to WordPress and WooCommerce code. I've been provided with some working code that resides in the plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php

The function is pretty simple, it simply fetches for an array of data from a remote site and makes use of the JSON returned to find the matching SKUs and inject them as items in the product list.

Works quite nicely, however, as I'm new to Woo & WP, I'm hoping someone might be able to show me how I can transform this code into the proper way of it being defined as a plugin?

I'm hoping its just a case of wrapping some additional code around the function, but I'm unsure as to where to start

any tips greatly appreciated

```
if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {

    $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

    $cat = explode('/', $actual_link);

    if ($cat[4] == 'my-product-list') {

        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        $data = array( 'email' =>  $current_user->user_email);
        $response = wp_remote_post( 'https://www.shop.com/remote-data/', array( 'data' => $data ) );

        $curl = 'https://www.shop.com/remote-data/';

        $response = wp_remote_get( $curl );
        $rows = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) ;
        $decode = json_decode(stripslashes($rows), true);

        global $wpdb;

        $product_id = array();

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($decode as $single_data) {
            foreach ($single_data['items'] as $data) {
                $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_sku' AND meta_value = '".$data."'" );
                $product_id[$i] = $result[0]->post_id;
                $i++;
            }
        }

        $product_id = array_filter(array_unique($product_id));
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post__in' => $product_id
        );

        //The Query
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();

            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to hook it into `woocommerce_before_main_content`

Like so:

```
function fetch_shop_data() {
   // your code
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'fetch_shop_data');
```